# Codenvy: Can't run simple Hello World java program

Tags: java, codenvy

I'm trying to run a simple program:

```
public class Greet  {
     public static void main(String[] args)  {
            System.out.println("HELLO");
     }
}
```

But I get `/bin/bash: line 2: $'\r': command not found
python: can't open file '/projects/GreetTest/main.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory` as an output.

What can be done to make such simple console programs to be compiled and executed? I tried googling but had trouble finding a thorough tutorial.

**EDIT**: When I press run a `newCustom` is run:

```
# execute a JAR
java -jar ${current.project.path}/target/application.jar

# execute python script
python ${current.project.path}/main.py
```

I tried deleting the python part so it's now:

```
# execute a JAR
java -jar ${current.project.path}/target/application.jar
```

and it gives an error:

`Error: Unable to access jarfile /projects/GreetTest/target/application.jar`

My file is titled  `Greet.java`.

Comment: what command are you typing ro run this?

Comment: It looks like you're  trying to run this with a python interpreter

Comment: How do you try to run in? The snippet is `Java` source and in the error mesage the `Python` executable complains about a missed file. How should we know what you did wrong?

Comment: read the error!! it says python: .... you need to compile your java program using a jdk not a python compiler.. or else rename the file Greet.py, say print "Hello"... if you are running a python program.

Comment: @Adam Jaamour I edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Rename the file to be called `Greet.java`. That file should contain exactly the code that you posted in your question, nothing more.
2. Run `javac Greet.java`.
3. Run `java Greet`.

This assumes that you have a working JDK installed on your machine.

As stated in the comments before, it seems that you are trying to run your Java code with a Python interpreter. Python is a completely different programming environment.

---

*Update:* So, I had a look at Codenvy. They provide a complete Hello World example. Create a new workspace, select the "Java" quick start stack and add the `console-java-simple` project to the workspace. Then run the `console-java-simple: run` Maven task. You can get a list of the project's Maven tasks by pressing `Shift+F10`.

The `HelloWorld.java` file in their example is almost identical to your `Greet.java`.

Here's how to do it step by step:

1. Log in to Codenvy.
2. On the dashboard, click `Create Workspace` (under `Recent Workspaces`)
3. On the following page, in the "Select Stack" section, select the stack labeled `Java - Default Java Stack with JDK 8, Maven and Tomcat.` (not the preselected one that includes MySQL).
4. On the same page, in the "Projects" section, click `Add or Import Project` and check the `console-java-simple` project. Then click `Add`.
5. Click the big green `Create` button at the bottom, or the one in the upper right corner. The workspace gets created and the view switches to the new workspace. Wait until you see a notification in the upper right corner telling you that the `console-java-simple` project was successfully imported.
6. Press `Shift+F10`.
7. Double click the `run` Maven task.
8. See the output of the Maven build and finally the "Hello World" at the very bottom of the console.

In the project explorer, under `console-java-simple/src/main/java/org.eclipse.che.examples/`, you can find the `HelloWorld.java`.

---

*Update:* By the way, I don't think that Codenvy is the right tool to get started with Java. It's not meant to be a quick and easy way to play around with Java but instead a full blown IDE running in the browser. You have to deal with a lot of distractions from actual Java programming, like build tools (e.g. Maven) to get anything running.

If getting started with Java is what you are aiming at, I'd recommend to find a way to get a JDK installed locally and then play around with that.

Comment: You mean run it in my command promt? I don't have anything related to java installed on my Windows machine. I was hoping to find a 100% online environment. Am I mistaken for thinking codenvy could provide one/

Comment: Yes, I overlooked the "Codenvy" part in the title. Could be a good idea to make it more clear in you question text that you are specifically asking about Codenvy, and not just Java in general. As you can see, people will most of the time assume you want to run your code example locally if not specified otherwise very clearly.

Comment: Does the Codenvy specific part I added to my answer help you?

Comment: I tried your answer, but can't figure out how you run `console-java-simple: run` Maven task? I opened a newly created workspace, is it supposed to be under a Run tab? Sadly I don't have a choice since I can't install ide where I am.

Comment: I added a step by step explanation. Can you make it run by following those steps?

Comment: Thank you, it worked! Any chance you know some good tutorials for codenvy or something I could read to be able to use it more easily? That's my only option at the moment.

Comment: Codenvy is based on Eclipse Che which is basically a web application version of the classic Eclipse IDE. So, many things that you can learn about Eclipse will be applicable to Codenvy, too.

At a minimum, besides Java programming itself, you'll probably have to know about basic Maven usage in order to do anything meaningful with Codenvy.

Codenvy itself has Tutorials and a User Guide available: https://codenvy.io/docs/

Comment: Ok, I'll take a look at that. Thank you so much, you are super cool!

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do to run your program is to remove current macro and add a new one.

In order to do it select second icon from the left in the top left corner ("Manage Commands"). Then select current macro and remove it. Next click plus sign and from drop down list select "Java".

If you don't like default name of the macro you can rename it. In order to do so double-click it, enter new name and then click "SAVE" button located below.

[image: screenshot]